# Создание метода, хранящего в себе строковую переменную

Tags: java

Делаю текстовую игру, в которой при старте игры пользователя просят ввести имя таким методом:

```
public static String MainCharacterInitialization() {
System.out.println("*Введите ваше имя*");
Scanner MainCharacterScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String MainCharacterName = MainCharacterScanner.nextLine();
return MainCharacterName;
}
```

он вызывается из другого метода

```
public static void CharacterName() {
    String GGName = MainCharacter();
    System.out.println(GGName + ": ");
}
```

Метод `CharacterName()` должен инициализировать имя *ГГ* перед диалогом (он прописан в другом методе) пример:

Кислый: Эй, что ты делаешь, завязывай, иначе я позову старшего!

Но загвоздка в том, что при вызове метода, который хранит имя *ГГ*, каждый раз  вызывается и метод с вводом имени *ГГ*, вот и сложность у меня появляется: как реализовать такой код, чтобы при первом запуске метода `CharacterName()`, был вызван метод `MainCharacterInitialization`, в котором пользователь ввёл своё имя и оно сохранилось в определённую переменную (например `GGName`) и потом, перед каждым диалогом чтобы я мог вызывать метод, в котором была бы переменная, которой я присвоил введённое пользователем имя (через `scanner`), примерно чтобы в итоге вот так выглядел код в методе с вызовом имени:

```
    CharacterName();
    System.out.println("Тебя как звать то?");
```

Что увидеть должен пользователь:

Сизый: Тебя как звать то?

(сизый - имя, которое условно ввёл пользователь)

Comment: Так, я спрошу проще. А ты уже освоил ооп в java? Просто у тебя все методы статические... Я могу тебе предложить пример класса сохранения, где будет хранится имя гг и какие-либо внутриигровые состояния (инвентарь и информация о принятых решениях). Но вопрос в том, нужно ли тебе это? Ты пишешь исключительно одними функциями?

Comment: Я только в процессе освоения ООП, но буду очень рад увидеть пример класса сохранения и попробовать разобраться что к чему. Я как раз потом собирался реализовать сохранение процесса игры  и по этому поводу задать вопрос, как это правильнее сделать)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вот и моя простыня. Тут тебе еще куча всяких примеров работы с классами. Не гарантирую что будет в начале понятно, но все равно удобней в начале живой пример увидеть.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GameState {
    //Здесь пример класса с дженериками, до этого еще далеко, но малоли... Да и удобнее он тебе будет.
    private HashMap<String, Object> states = new HashMap<>();
    //Этот параметр записывается при создании объекта класса, после чего его нельзя изменить. Только если создать объект заного.
    private final String userName;

    /**
     * Конструктор, который запрашивает имя сам. Подойдет, если игра начинается с начала.
     */
    public GameState(){
        userName = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    }

    /**
     * Конструктор, который получает имя извне. Подойдет, если игра загружается из сохранения.
     */
    public GameState(String userName, HashMap<String, Object> states){
        //Если параметр функции совпадает с переменной самого класса, к переменной можно получить доступ через this
        this.userName = userName;
        this.states = states;
    }

    /**
     * Возвращает имя героя.
     * @return
     */
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    /**
     * Возвращает какой либо параметр по ключу(строке)
     * @param key
     * @return
     */
    public Object getState(String key) {
        return states.get(key);
    }

    /**
     * Сохраняет параметр по заданному ключу.
     * @param key
     * @param param параметр может быть любого типа.
     */
    public void setState(String key, Object param) {
        states.put(key, param);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ого, до того как увидел ваш код, думал что хоть что-то начинаю понимать в основах джавы, но теперь понял что я скорее всего полный ноль и даже то простых текстовых игрушек мне далеко, пойду читать тогда литературу. Кстати, может посоветуете что?(желательно на русском языке)

Comment: Вот на чем я учил основы ооп уже не вспомню. (По большей части многое осиливал на практике) Тут главное понять, что из себя представляет ооп, а с остальным пойдет легче. Знания (о java8) я обновлял по книге "Java 8. Полное руководство" Шилдт Г.. Описание принципов ооп там есть, а насколько хорошее - не знаю.

Comment: Размеров книги не стоит боятся, там с какой-то главы просто идет бездумное перечисление библиотек и их функционала.

Answer (score 1):

Послушай, мне кажется у тебя неправильное представление о Java. Ты пробуешь мыслить линейно запихивая в один класс всю логику. Тогда как у тебя должно быть много классов. Попробовал примерно сформулировать:

```
class MainCharacter {

    String MainCharacterName;

    MainCharacter(String MainCharacterName){
        this.MainCharacterName = MainCharacterName;
    }

}

class Talking {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("*Введите ваше имя*");
        Scanner MainCharacterScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String mainCharacterName = MainCharacterScanner.nextLine();

        MainCharacter one = new MainCharacter(mainCharacterName);

        //Вопрос
        System.out.println(one.MainCharacterName + "Тебя как звать то?");

    }

}
```

Comment: Допустим вынесу, а как ей присвоить значение, введённое пользователем?

Comment: Точно также как ты это делал внутри метода. Переменная класса видна всем членам класса (т.е. внутри всех методов).

Comment: Я просто не понимаю как сделать, чтобы при первом вызове переменной, ей присвоилось значение, которое введёт пользователь, а при последующих вызовах переменной, чтобы в ней уже хранилось ранее введённое значение переменной

Comment: переделал свой ответ тебе, надеюсь так понятнее будет

Comment: Блин, код работает идеально, так как мне нужно, но вот как он работает, не очень понимаю, а если быть точнее, то из класса Talking всё понятно, а вот как происходит процесс выполнение кода в классе MainCharacterName, пока не могу понять.
Извини за наглость, но я просто обязан спросить, можешь хотя бы вкратце объяснить что происходит, когда выполнение когда доходит до: 

MainCharacter one = new MainCharacter(mainCharacterName);

Comment: Тебе нужно почитать про объекты. В данном случае, class MainCharacter создает объект твоего героя... для создания объекта используется конструктор принимающий в параметры имя. Если ты потом добавишь своему главному герою жизни, амуницию и т.п. все это можно просто сделать в этом самом классе... и все данные из него будут доступны через вызов свойств объекта или его методов... точно по такому же принципу как one.MainCharacterName

Comment: Сегодня доделал эту мини игру, но столкнулся с проблемой, в IDE корректно отображается имя, которое ввёл пользователь на Русском языке, а когда делаю .exe оболочку через Launch4jc и запускаю, то имя, введённое на Русском языке некорректно отображается:
Андрей - ??¤а??
Думал проблема в том что String использует не ту кодировку, которая требуется, хотел поменять на char с кодировкой Unicode, но как оказалось Scanner не работает с переменными типа char, есть варианты как-то это решить? (Может это при переводе .jar в .exe что-то происходит с кодировками?)